# Picking php version for the execution of spatie/phpunit-watcher

Tags: php, phpunit

So my issue is that my current system has many versions of php with plenty of `php.ini` files.

The issue is that when I try to run `phpunit-watcher` with the PHP version that I need, when triggering the tests it goes to the default version.

I've looked through the documentation but it doesn't say anything on the topic.

Is there a way to pick the PHP version which `spatie/phpunit-watcher` to use?

The package is [spatie/phpunit-watcher](https://github.com/spatie/phpunit-watcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `phpunit` and `phpunit-watcher` both use the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Have a look at their source-code:

- [phpunit#L1](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/phpunit#L1)
- [phpunit-watcher#L1](https://github.com/spatie/phpunit-watcher/blob/master/phpunit-watcher#L1)

Now you probably execute `phpunit-watcher` with the `php` binary of your choice i.e.:

```
/usr/bin/php-7.3 ~/.composer/bin/phpunit-watcher
```

... but `phpunit` itself is launched as a sub-process of `phpunit-watcher`. That's why `phpunit` is still executed with the first `php` executable found in your `PATH`.

The solution is to ensure the PHP version that you want to use for both `phpunit-watcher` and `phpunit` is the first `php` in your `PATH`. The current version used can be found with:

```
which php
```

There's no option for `phpunit` or `phpunit-watcher` themselves to switch the PHP interpreter!

Instead you can use tools like `update-alternatives` to switch the current system PHP version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```